# android detect if night

Tags: android

Is there a better way than this?

```
Boolean isNight;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if(hour < 6 || hour > 18){
    isNight = true;
} else {
    isNight = false;
}
```

It just checks if hour is between 7pm and 5am.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Well, you could use the device's camera to assess the lightness/darkness of surrounding, combined with measuring the time it takes for GPS to obtain a location fix as a hint whether the user is actually outside... No, I'm not being serious :) A simple solution like your current one (bar some obvious fixes, like using `boolean` and getting rid of `if`) is most likely the best you can get.

Comment: Isn't there a way to detect if the device is currently in NightMode ?
I see there is a way to change the device mode but i don't see how you can read the current mode.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am trying to solve the same problem. UiModeManager doesn't seem to be very helpful.

Comment: @mstewart Nope. I didn't really need a lot of accuracy, so I just stuck with assigning true/false based on the hour of the day. I imagine you could tie that in with a local time of sunset lookup through a weather service of some sort, but I didn't care to go that far with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a big difference, but you can make an assignment:

```
isNight = hour < 6 || hour > 18;
```

Comment: I'm currently doing it this, but I think it's too inaccurate, especially as you approach the poles. Ideally, you need to check hours, latitude and months (and possibly any special rules for certain countries). 

EDIT: Or have defaults for summer and winter, and let the user adjust them maybe.

Answer (score 3):

**values**\values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isNightMode">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**values-night**\values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isNightMode">true</bool>
</resources>
```

And Now, check it on your your class.java

```
public boolean isNightMode(){
    return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isNightMode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UiModeManager to enable CarMode and NIGHT mode is set to AUTO. You can get a reference to the current theme used by declaring an attribute to look up at runtime.

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <!--  Theme name reference -->
    <attr name="metaThemeName" format="string"/>
</resources>
```

**values-night**/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="metaThemeName">night</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

java.class

```
...
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.metaThemeName, outValue, true);
    boolean isNight="night".equals(outValue.string);
...
```