# Xamarin.Forms how to change the Theme based on time of the day

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have scenario like this: Have two themes Light and Dark . I have a binding from the viewmodel what theme to add. I just don't know how to get time from device and organize . I need after 7 PM everyday the theme change to Dark , its Light by default. How to organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suggest that you create an property in the `App.xaml.cs`, in the app Start/Resume methods, verify the hour of the day, and then on your ViewModel you will have access to this value.

App.xaml.cs:

```
public bool IsDarkTheme;

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}

public void SetTheme()
{
    TimeSpan day = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    if (!(day.Hours < 19 && day.Hours > 6))
    {
        IsDarkTheme = true;
    }
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    // Handle when your app starts
    SetTheme();
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
    SetTheme();
}
```

Note: if the user opened the app before 7pm and resumes it after, and you want the page that was resumed to change apearence, you will need to add this to the pages (if you do this, you no longer need to define the value in the ViewModel constructor):

On the Pages xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    ((TheViewModelAssociated)BindingContext).TheViewModelProperty = App.IsDarkTheme;
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Your ViewModel you access it like this:

```
App.IsDarkTheme
```

Comment: and this SetTheme is?

Comment: Is just a method i create to be called from the Start/Resume methods to set the IsDarkTheme property

Comment: Aham ad how you organize themes? In resources?

Comment: @Razzzz also take note that if the user resumes the app after 7pm when the app was opened before, you will need to add a verification on the pages OnApearing, i will add it to my anwser

Comment: @Razzzz you should create a style like for example: ' <Style x:Key="DarkTheme" TargetType="Label"><Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" /></Style> ' in the <Application.Resources> and then use the StaticResource and present it depending on the binding value, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165202/binding-to-staticresource-with-a-property-of-view-model-in-xamarin-forms or you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic

Comment: One last question. Instead of add static time to change themes, is there any solution to read from the device? I need Dark Theme when its night

Comment: Can the device know when its night?

Comment: @Razzzz check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250367/android-detect-if-night , it uses the same method as i did, and no, i don't think there is a way to know when it's "night" since night is a very broad subject, since for the same timezone, it can still have daylight in some places, and in others it's already dark, so using the day Hours is the best option

Comment: based on gps location?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208849/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-razzzz).